# msg post on user facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook, post, using

i want to post on user fb wall whoever login... i m using this code.. it is working fine on app administrator wall but failed to post on other user... plz help

```
<?php
  include_once ('facebook-php-sdk-master\src\facebook.php');
  $appId = 'app id'; //Facebook App ID
  $secret = 'app secret'; // Facebook App Secret
  $returnurl = 'localhost/check/index4.php';  //return url (url to script)
  $permissions = 'publish_actions, manage_pages';  //Required facebook permissions
  $fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>$appId, 'secret'=>$secret));
  $fbuser= $fb->getUser();

if($fbuser){


if(isset($_POST['text']) and $_POST['text']!='' ){
    try{
        $message= array(
            'message'=>$_POST['text']
        );
        $url='/me/feed';
        $result= $fb->api($url,'POST',$message);
        if($result){
            echo "Data posted to facebook Succefull";
        }else
        {
            echo"Not Posted";
        }
    }catch(FacebookApiException $error){
    echo $error->getMessage();
}

}

  `
try{
    /*
    $qry='select page_id, name from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_admin where uid='.$fbuser.' )';
    $page=$fb->api(array('method'=>'fql.query','query'=>$qry));
    if(empty($page)){
        echo "user do not have any page to post";
    }
    else{
        echo "user has page!";
    }
    */
    echo '<form action="" method="post" name="check">';
    echo '<textarea name="text"></textarea>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Post"/>';
    echo '</form>';
}catch(FacebookApiException $error){
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

}

`

```
else {
$loginurl= $fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>$permissions, 'redirect-url'=>$returnurl));
echo '<a href="'.$loginurl.'" >Login with Fb</a>';
}

?>
```

*It send comment on administrator wall only*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog):

> Apps requesting more than public_profile, email and the user_friends permission must be reviewed by Facebook before those permissions can be requested from people.

publish_actions and manage_pages need to get reviewed by Facebook before they work for anyone else. Without approval, they will only work for uses with a role in the App (Admin/Dev/Tester). See this page for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Comment: Sir i login to my page using fb login and allow app to to publish comments... but the issue is when i comment on my wall it gives error **(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**

Comment: you don´t want to use the graph api? dude, you ARE using the graph api already. "/me/feed" is an endpoint of the graph api, for example... anyway, check out my answer. you need to go through a review process or the permissions will not work for other users.

Comment: so what permissions i need to add?

Comment: what permissions i need to add so that every user post comment on there wall by using my page

Comment: check out my answer, you need to get your permissions approved if it only works for admins. it´s all in the answer, including a link to the facebook docs that´s very important.

Comment: yes, and those permissions need to get approved by facebook before users can use them

Comment: and it will not be authorised if the final user can't add his comment. i think the custom story of open graph must be used.